# combine two lapply functions into 1 function in R

Tags: r

I have to apply functions which i wan't to combine together to 1 function.

```
list1 <- lapply(seq(1,100), function(x) topFeaturesAllSamples[[x]])
list2 <- lapply(seq(1,100), function(x) list1[[x]][topDifferentialExpressed[[x]][[1]],])
```

list1 is a list of 100
containing different gene expressions in each list

```
[[1]]

          TCGA-AG-A016 TCGA-AG-3887 TCGA-AG-3581 TCGA-AG-A00C TCGA-AG-3594
TGFBR2     11.407178    10.987474    11.704051    10.711772    11.861520
MAML2       7.080093     7.789335     7.713779     8.645695     6.777620
EIF5A      13.724940    14.222748    13.018575    12.640773    12.604787
RNF38       9.184958     9.038283     9.625290     9.361620     9.427665
EIF5AL1    11.796275    12.350587    11.327539    10.889184    10.994424
WRAP53      8.216806     9.088202     7.750620     7.578281     7.648888

[[2]]
          TCGA-AG-A016 TCGA-AG-3887 TCGA-AG-3581 TCGA-AG-A00C TCGA-AG-3594
TGFBR2    11.407178    10.987474    11.704051    10.711772    11.861520
MAML2      7.080093     7.789335     7.713779     8.645695     6.777620
WRAP53     8.216806     9.088202     7.750620     7.578281     7.648888    
EIF5A     13.724940    14.222748    13.018575    12.640773    12.604787
YAP1      11.086030    11.162294    10.848429    11.058929     9.836591
TMEM43    10.732424    10.765218    11.214908    11.106273    10.508263
```

list2 is also a list of 100 which represents a part of list1 [[1]]

```
 [[1]]
          TCGA-AG-A016 TCGA-AG-3887 TCGA-AG-3581 TCGA-AG-A00C TCGA-AG-3594
TGFBR2     11.407178    10.987474    11.704051    10.711772    11.861520
MAML2       7.080093     7.789335     7.713779     8.645695     6.777620
EIF5A      13.724940    14.222748    13.018575    12.640773    12.604787

[[2]]
           TCGA-AG-A016 TCGA-AG-3887 TCGA-AG-3581 TCGA-AG-A00C TCGA-AG-3594
TGFBR2     11.407178    10.987474    11.704051    10.711772    11.861520
MAML2       7.080093     7.789335     7.713779     8.645695     6.777620
EIF5A      13.724940    14.222748    13.018575    12.640773    12.604787
RNF38       9.184958     9.038283     9.625290     9.361620     9.427665

[[3]]
          TCGA-AG-A016 TCGA-AG-3887 TCGA-AG-3581 TCGA-AG-A00C TCGA-AG-3594
TGFBR2     11.407178    10.987474    11.704051    10.711772    11.861520
MAML2       7.080093     7.789335     7.713779     8.645695     6.777620
EIF5A      13.724940    14.222748    13.018575    12.640773    12.604787
RNF38       9.184958     9.038283     9.625290     9.361620     9.427665
EIF5AL1    11.796275    12.350587    11.327539    10.889184    10.994424
```

the problem is i want to have a function that repeat the lapply of list1 198 times
so the number behind de [[x]][[1]] has to be changed every iteration
so instead of

```
  list2 <- lapply(seq(1,100), function(x) list1[[x]][topDifferentialExpressed[[x]][[1]],])
  list2.1 <- lapply(seq(1,100), function(x) list1[[x]][topDifferentialExpressed[[x]][[2]],])
  list2.2 <- lapply(seq(1,100), function(x) list1[[x]][topDifferentialExpressed[[x]][[3]],])
    ....
    ....
  list2.198 <- lapply(seq(1,100), function(x) list1[[x]][topDifferentialExpressed[[x]][[198]],])
```

so list2.1 should look something like this

```
 [[1]]
          TCGA-AG-A016 TCGA-AG-3887 TCGA-AG-3581 TCGA-AG-A00C TCGA-AG-3594
TGFBR2    11.407178    10.987474    11.704051    10.711772    11.861520
MAML2      7.080093     7.789335     7.713779     8.645695     6.777620
WRAP53     8.216806     9.088202     7.750620     7.578281     7.648888   


[[2]] 
          TCGA-AG-A016 TCGA-AG-3887 TCGA-AG-3581 TCGA-AG-A00C TCGA-AG-3594
TGFBR2    11.407178    10.987474    11.704051    10.711772    11.861520
MAML2      7.080093     7.789335     7.713779     8.645695     6.777620
WRAP53     8.216806     9.088202     7.750620     7.578281     7.648888    
EIF5A     13.724940    14.222748    13.018575    12.640773    12.604787

[[3]]
          TCGA-AG-A016 TCGA-AG-3887 TCGA-AG-3581 TCGA-AG-A00C TCGA-AG-3594
TGFBR2    11.407178    10.987474    11.704051    10.711772    11.861520
MAML2      7.080093     7.789335     7.713779     8.645695     6.777620
WRAP53     8.216806     9.088202     7.750620     7.578281     7.648888    
EIF5A     13.724940    14.222748    13.018575    12.640773    12.604787
YAP1      11.086030    11.162294    10.848429    11.058929     9.836591
```

etc etc this should repeated for all of the 198 lists from list1 i want to have one function that repeat this process 198 times.
i tried a double for loop already and this was resulting in that my R got stuck.

i want to eventually have 1 list containing 198 lists and each of the 198 list should also contain a list of 100 containing gene expressions for each list

is there a efficient way to do this?

Comment: You aren't really using any functions in your `lapply` loop. You are simply reshaping data. I'm not sure if you are trying to extract nested lists from `topFeaturesAllSamples` and `topDifferentialExpressed` or if you are simply unaware of the difference between `[i]` and `[[i]]` subsetting in the context of an R dataframe. Without any idea as to what `test` and `topDifferentialExpressed`, it is difficult trying to understand what you are trying to do. You should do a `dput(head(x))` dump of your data containers.

Comment: And if you really want to nest your list then you can do the following `L = list();for (i in 1:198){L[i] <- lapply(seq(1,100), function(x) test[[x]][topDifferentialExpressed[[x]][[i]],])}`

Comment: i tried that, but the problem is that it takes to long to execute

Comment: You'll want to look at `mapply` and `rapply`

Comment: `mapply/rapply` are merely wrappers for `lapply/sapply`. They offer no improvement over `for` loops. Your `list2...list2.198` code should have about the same execution time as a `for` loop assignment. If speed is not acceptable, you need to ditch the list idea and try to go with `library(data.table)`.

Comment: which function in data.table do i need to use?